# Wordpress count private posts in wp_list_categories

Tags: php, wordpress

Since I didn't find anything helpful on the web I'd like to ask:

In WP you can with `wp_list_categories` and `show_count=1` and `hide_empty=0` list all categories (even empty ones) with the number of posts at the end.

example output: General (9)

So when I make a private post and publish it the count for General remains on 9.

Is there a way I can also show the count of private posts?

Comment: Not with that function. You could make your own query though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found quite a solution for this:

```
$args = array(
    'include'  => array( 8,9,10 ),  //categories that contains the private articles
    'title_li' => '',
    'show_count' => 0,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    );

$categories = get_categories($args);

foreach($categories as $category) { 

$args_priv = array(
    'cat' => $category->term_id,
    'post_status'    => array( 'private','publish' ),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args_priv );

$count = '('. $the_query->found_posts .')';

    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name.'</a> '.$count.'<br />';

}
```